# Capturing a signature event with Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to be able to capture a "Sign" event, see below.
However Worksheet_Change is not triggered. Please advise

[image]

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

  If ThisWorkbook.Signatures.Count > 0 Then
  
  End If

End Sub
```

Also, it seems no Workbook event is triggered as well, tried to capture any the following:

[image]

Comment: Makes sense. The *workbook* is changing, not the worksheet.

Comment: Edited in order to add more information: no WORKBOOK event seems to be triggered as well

Comment: There is no built-in event for this. You could perhaps check `.Signatures.Count` on a timely basis as a workaround.

Comment: Are you (and all potential users of the Workbook) using Windows devices?

Comment: @JohnM: yes, it is only Windows based

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code creates an event handler for whenever the Workbook (that the code is within) window is activated. This is different to the built-in Workbook_Activate event in that it triggers **any time** the window is activated ... even if it was only an Excel dialog (such as the 'Sign' dialog) that was previously in front of it.

This code comes with a caution though. It uses the Windows API to insert a 'hook' into the message loop to listen to window events. During development, if the 'hook' is active and a window event is passed into this code, it will crash Excel if you are blocking VBA code from running (eg if you are stepping through code with F8) or if you are editing the code that handles the windows events. So, two things:

1. Save / backup frequently and often!
2. I include code so that the 'hook' is not added automatically during development and/or on my development device (but that the hook is added automatically on end-user devices) ... so add (for example in a standard Module named 'SignatureUtils')

```
' are we running code on the development device?
Function IsDevDevice() As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next
    IsDevDevice = StrComp(Environ$("username"), "XXXXX", vbTextCompare) = 0
End Function
```

... changing "XXXXX" to your username ... or you might need to adjust the return value from this Function for your needs.

Then add the signature-specific code ... this particular code is just going to show you a message box when a signature is added or removed and you need to amend this to your needs ... noting the warning above about crashing Excel (in my code, I've again added this to Module 'SignatureUtils')

```
' a window 'event' occurred with this workbook now being active
Sub WorkbookActivated()
    Static lSignatureCount As Long
    ' has the number of signatures changed?
    If ThisWorkbook.Signatures.Count > lSignatureCount Then
        lSignatureCount = ThisWorkbook.Signatures.Count
        MsgBox "Signature added to Workbook"
    ElseIf ThisWorkbook.Signatures.Count < lSignatureCount Then
        lSignatureCount = ThisWorkbook.Signatures.Count
        MsgBox "Signature removed from Workbook"
    End If
End Sub
```

Next add the 'hook' code ... the best way to learn more about the Windows API functions and constants used here is on the MS [CBTProc callback function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/ms644977(v=vs.85)) page but, in summary, `SetHook` tells the Windows OS that we want to be informed when a 'window event' (for example, a window is activated, gets focus, is created, is destroyed etc) takes place. `UnHook` tells the Windows OS that we want to stop being informed of those events. `LogWhetherHooked` is a small convenience procedure that you, as a developer, can run to test whether a hook is currently present or not. And `Callback` is the procedure that is called by the Windows OS when a 'window event' occurs. I've added comments to this procedure to explain what it is doing, however, it essentially calls the `WorkbookActivated` procedure that we added to the 'SignatureUtils' Module whenever the window for this Workbook is activated. Add this code to a standard Module named 'Hook')

```
Option Explicit
Option Private Module

' see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/ms644977(v=vs.85)

#If VBA7 Then
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetCurrentThreadId Lib "Kernel32" () As Long
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function SetWindowsHookEx Lib "user32" Alias "SetWindowsHookExA" _
            (ByVal idHook As Long, ByVal lpfn As LongPtr, ByVal hmod As LongPtr, ByVal dwThreadId As Long) As LongPtr
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function CallNextHookEx Lib "user32" _
            (ByVal hHook As LongPtr, ByVal nCode As Long, ByVal wParam As LongPtr, lParam As Any) As LongPtr
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function UnhookWindowsHookEx Lib "user32" _
            (ByVal hhk As LongPtr) As Long

    Private mlHookID As LongPtr
#Else
    Private Declare Function GetCurrentThreadId Lib "kernel32" () As Long
    Private Declare Function SetWindowsHookEx Lib "user32" Alias "SetWindowsHookExA" _
            (ByVal idHook As Long, ByVal lpfn As Long, ByVal hmod As Long,ByVal dwThreadId As Long) As Long
    Private Declare Function CallNextHookEx Lib "user32" _
            (ByVal hHook As Long, ByVal ncode As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, lParam As Any) As Long
    Private Declare Function UnhookWindowsHookEx Lib "user32" _
            (ByVal hHook As Long) As Long

    Private mlHookID As Long
#End If


Const WH_CBT As Long = 5

Const HCBT_MOVESIZE As Long = 0
Const HCBT_MINMAX As Long = 1
Const HCBT_QS As Long = 2
Const HCBT_CREATEWND As Long = 3
Const HCBT_DESTROYWND As Long = 4
Const HCBT_ACTIVATE As Long = 5
Const HCBT_CLICKSKIPPED As Long = 6
Const HCBT_KEYSKIPPED As Long = 7
Const HCBT_SYSCOMMAND As Long = 8
Const HCBT_SETFOCUS As Long = 9

' ******************************************************************************************************************
' * Do not step through code in this Module (eg using F8) and ensure to always manually call Unhook before editing *
' * code in this Module or in other Modules called by code in this Module ... very high chance of crashing Excel   *
' ******************************************************************************************************************


' Set a 'window hook'
Sub SetHook()
    If mlHookID = 0 Then
        mlHookID = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_CBT, AddressOf Callback, 0, GetCurrentThreadId)
    End If
End Sub


' Remove a previously-set 'window hook'
Sub UnHook()
    If mlHookID <> 0 Then
        UnhookWindowsHookEx mlHookID
        mlHookID = 0
    End If
End Sub


' Log whether a hook is currently set
Sub LogWhetherHooked()
    Debug.Print IIf(mlHookID = 0, "Not hooked", "Hooked")
End Sub


' The hook callback ... called every time a window 'event' takes place on the device ... see documentation at the
' above link for more details
#If VBA7 Then
Private Function Callback(ByVal nCode As Long, ByVal wParam As LongPtr, ByVal lParam As Long) As LongPtr
#Else
Private Function Callback(ByVal nCode As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, ByVal lParam As Long) As Long
#End If
    ' we must handle all errors in here otherwise we could crash Excel
    On Error GoTo errExit
    
    If nCode >= 0 Then ' as required ... see documentation at the above link
        If nCode = HCBT_ACTIVATE Then ' a window has been activated
            If wParam = ThisWorkbook.Windows(1).hwnd Then ' it is this workbook's window
                SignatureUtils.WorkbookActivated
            End If
        End If
    End If
    
errExit:
    ' ensure any other hooks (eg put in place by other apps) are called correctly
    Callback = CallNextHookEx(mlHookID, nCode, wParam, lParam)
End Function
```

Note that the above code includes conditional compilation depending for whether 32 or 64 bit Office is being used ... and, unfortunately, I do not have a 32 bit device to test it on ... if you are using a 32 bit device and you get compilation errors with this code (especially in the 'Declare' lines) then please let me know!!

The final element is to ensure `SetHook` is called when the Workbook opens and `UnHook` is called when the Workbook is closed ... this code must be added to the ThisWorkbook Module:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    If Not SignatureUtils.IsDevDevice Then
        Hook.SetHook
    End If
End Sub


Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    Hook.UnHook
End Sub
```

As mentioned above, this will not automatically set the hook on your device (if you included `IsDevDevice`) but if you just want the hook to always be set (including on your device) then remove the 'If' from `Workbook_Open`.

To manually set the hook for testing during development, run the `SetHook` procedure ... but (per comments above) remember to save your Workbook first.

Comment: Thank you vey much John for your detailed solution